# Auto populate/ pre fill input field with text form the h1 using jquery

Tags: ajax, jquery

I would like to have the first input in my form pre filled in with the text from the pages h1, how would I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("input:first").val($("h1").html());
```

Comment: the :first seems to be causing the issue but will maybe have do it using the class